# Python - retrieve a specific sentence from a large text file

Tags: python, list, count, frequency

Here is my sentence:

```
s = "& how are you then? I am fine, % and i want to found some food #meat with vegetable# #tea# #cake# and #tea# so on."
```

I am looking to count the frequency of words  bound by `# #` in the sentence `s`.

I want the following output

```
[("meat with vegetable", 1)
 ("tea", 2)
 ("cake", 1)]
```

Thanks a lot for your help and time!

Comment: consider my revision to your post!

Comment: Thanks for your nice revision

Comment: Did you try anything yourself ? This is not a code writing service

Comment: ['meat with vegetable', 'tea', 'cake', 'tea']
Counter({'tea': 2, 'cake': 1, 'meat with vegetable': 1})

Comment: this is now corresponding to  'piglei's advice , i got following result, ['meat with vegetable', 'tea', 'cake', 'tea']
Counter({'tea': 2, 'cake': 1, 'meat with vegetable': 1})

Comment: but i am confuced about "here i got an txt file with lot of lines different sentence, do you know how to import as s"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the power of `re` and `Counter`, this task can be easily done:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = "& how are you then? I am fine, % and i want to found some food #meat with vegetable# #tea# #cake# and #tea# so on."

In [3]: re.findall(r'#([^#]*)#', s)
Out[3]: ['meat with vegetable', 'tea', 'cake', 'tea']

In [4]: from collections import Counter

In [5]: Counter(re.findall(r'#([^#]*)#', s))
Out[5]: Counter({'tea': 2, 'cake': 1, 'meat with vegetable': 1})
```

Get more information by reading the document on [python re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: I am new in python, you mean using re.find() and re.count()?

Comment: please give some more hits, i am new in python

Comment: Thanks a lot, i read your post carefully, now i understand now. thanks

Comment: here i got an txt file with lot of lines different sentence, do you know how to import as s.

Comment: Thanks for the hitting, now i fixed my problem.